# Cannot run executable after extracting tar.gz

Tags: software-installation, tar, executable, ide, extract

(Ubuntu version : 17.04 Zesty Zapus)

Hi,

I have downloaded an IDE for C/C++ programming called "MinGW Developer Studio" from [this link](http://vaultec.mbnet.fi/files/miscellaneous/mingwstudio/mingw-devstudio_linux-2.06.tar.gz). After extracting the files to a folder, I cannot run the executable inside either by double-clicking or by navigating to the folder in the terminal and typing ./MinGWStudio (the name of the executable).

The path of the parent folder is **/home/hp/MinGWStudio**

When I type the command "file MinGWStudio" I get the following output:

> MinGWStudio: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux
>   2.2.5,

When I navigate to the folder in terminal and type "MinGWStudio" I get the following output:

> MinGWStudio: command not found

When I navigate to the folder and type the command ./MinGWStudio I get the following output:

> bash: ./MinGWStudio: No such file or directory

When I run the command **uname -a** I get the following output

> Linux hp-HP-Notebook 4.10.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 30
>   05:32:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

What can I do to run this executable? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `uname -a` show for your architecture on your CPU/system?  If you know it's 64-bit 17.04 then that makes it easier to answer, but we need to know what architecture your system has first.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have edited the question to add the details.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the /home/hp/MinGWStudio folder and type following:

sudo chmod +x MinGWStudio

and then start the program with:

./MinGWStudio

Make sure the spelling matches the file name.